# How to replace strings in bz2file python?

Tags: python, compression, str-replace, large-files, bz2

I need to replace string in in very large bz2file (python3), and file should not be decompressed and writing on the disk and rewriting again it should be replaced "on the fly".

I do:

```
#change the first line
with BZ2File(file_name) as xml_file:
   for i , string in enumerate(xml_file):
    if i == 0:
        string.replace(bytes('some_string', 'utf-8'), 
                       bytes('changed_str', 'utf-8'))
        break
```

This code doing nothing.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well, the first obvious mistake is that you just throw away the result of the `replace`...

Comment: ok, but if i write this manner:   ' with BZ2File(txt_file, mode='w') as f:
#     for i, line in enumerate(f):
#         if i == 0:
    f.write(bytes('************', 'utf-8'))' this writig all file? but i need a one string...

Comment: ok, but if i write this manner:                                                                     'f.write(bytes(string, 'utf-8'))'                                                                                 
this rewriting all file, but i need a one string...